# E: Type '<!DOCTYPE' is not known on line 1 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/winehq.list E: The list of sources could not be read

Tags: apt, sudo, gedit, software-sources, etc

line 1 does  not contain anything
I have checked this by using `sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list` command.

Got this error during repository update.

Comment: English, please, and add the entire content of /etc/apt/sources.list.d/winehq.list to your question. It sounds like you downloaded a web page into the winehq.list

Comment: First `LANG=C` and `cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/winehq.list` please add the output to your question.

Comment: Why did you look at `/etc/apt/sources.list`, when the error message told you the error was in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/winehq.list`? They're different files.